# Enabling LZMA(2) (i.e. `.xz`) compression in log4j2

Tags: configuration, compression, log4j2, lzma, xz

### Current state of world

Currently our `RollingFileAppender` in `log4j2.xml` uses Gzip compression:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile"
             fileName="logs/engine.log"
             filePattern="logs/engine.log.%i.gz">
```

### Goal

I would like to switch to LZMA(2) (i.e. `.xz`) compression, to enjoy an improved compression ratio.

### Attempt

I have tried changing `engine.log.%i.gz` to `engine.log.%i.xz` — as per [the documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DefaultRolloverStrategy):

> If the file pattern ends with `.gz`, `.zip`, `.bz2`, `.deflate`, `.pack200`, or `.xz` the resulting archive will be compressed using the compression scheme that matches the suffix. The formats bzip2, Deflate, Pack200 and XZ require Apache Commons Compress. In addition, XZ requires [XZ for Java](http://tukaani.org/xz/java.html).

Additionally I have ensured that I have a runtime dependency on [XZ for Java](http://tukaani.org/xz/java.html) — via `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <!-- Support Log4j2 Log compression schemes: ".gz", ".zip", ".bz2", ".deflate", ".pack200", [".xz" (part 1 of 2)] -->
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <!-- Support Log4j2 Log compression scheme [".xz" (part 2 of 2)] -->
    <groupId>org.tukaani</groupId>
    <artifactId>xz</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

### Result

When the RollingFileAppender is triggered: the archive created is indeed *named* `engines.log.1.xz` — as required.

**However**, its contents are incorrect:

#### Expectation

`engines.log.1.xz` should contain LZMA(2) compressed text

#### Actual

`engines.log.1.xz` instead contains plain, uncompressed text.

### Sanity checks

I confirm that the `org.tukaani:xz` and `org.apache.commons:commons-compress` successfully made it into the classpath of my jar:

```
 jar tf mycooljar.jar | grep tukaani
org/tukaani/
org/tukaani/xz/
…

 jar tf mycooljar.jar | grep org/apache/commons/compress
org/apache/commons/compress/
org/apache/commons/compress/changes/
…
```

This Java program is not deployed to a J2EE webserver. I believe its class loading is straightforward.

### Summary

I have correctly followed the instructions necessary to create `.gz` archives.

I believe the only additional step required to create `.xz` archives is: I must provide at runtime the [XZ for Java](http://tukaani.org/xz/java.html) artefact. I have done this.

Am I missing something here? I am tempted to believe one of the following:

- The functionality is broken
- The docs are incomplete/incorrect
- log4j2 fails to discover the class at runtime

Comment: I was able to find [some evidence](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=logging-log4j2.git;a=blob;f=log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/DefaultRolloverStrategy.java;h=e3b8ffe3c9a0cf83f4392c17786e8dc47f5046b5;hb=HEAD#l125) that perhaps I am expected to input `.xy` instead of `.xz`.

If I use `.xy`: the log4j2 RollingAppender _fails_ to produce archives. That is: it creates blank `.xy` files, and retains the unarchived plaintext as a `.log` file. It smells like a buggy implementation.

Comment: Here is the code I present as evidence from `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy`:

`static enum FileExtensions {
    XY(".xy") {
        @Override
        Action createCompressAction(final String renameTo, final String compressedName, final boolean deleteSource,
                 final int compressionLevel) {
             // One of "gz", "bzip2", "xz", "pack200", or "deflate".
             return new CommonsCompressAction("xy", source(renameTo), target(compressedName), deleteSource);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: [Issue raised with Apache to track this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1369) — assuming it is indeed a bug.

Comment: +10. It was a bug and will be addressed in the next release. Thanks for raising this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Remko Popma confirmed that this is a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1369?focusedCommentId=15245926&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15245926):

- `log4j-core` accepted only `*.xy` as a matching pattern — whereas the docs suggested that `*.xz` was the required input.
- `"xy"` was being passed into `new CommonsCompressAction(…)` instead of the required `"xz"`.

These were both presumed to be typos: the proposed resolution was to change both to `xz`.

[Gary Gregory wrote a fix](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1369?focusedCommentId=15246681&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15246681). The fix is presently in `master` of `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.6-SNAPSHOT`, so should release with `2.6`.